# How can I split a comma-delimited value into multiple rows?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have `table1` query string that pulls the following from a remote table whereby `myKeys` is actually a comma-delimited list:

```
table1:  myKeys varchar, myCount int, myComment varchar
```

I need to update a local 2008r2 table based on:

```
table2: split somehow - myKeys int, myCount int, myComment varchar
```

Currently, I have an SSIS package that pulls the information and creates a local table. I've seen some answers using functions to feed a select statement (e.g. `myKeys`), but nothing that includes multiple fields e.g. (`myKeys`, `myCount`, `myComment`).

Comment: Are you really using DTS with SQL Server 2008, or did you mean SSIS? It looks like you could just split the value in a Script task to generate the `UPDATE` statements as you said; what have you tried and what problems do you have using the other answers that you found?

Comment: @Pondlife It's entirely possible that it's wrong. I just tried to fix the tags to the best of my ability. I should've probably checked if there was another "2008r2" first.

Comment: @Pondlife - I'm using SSIS, just holdover terminology.  I'm asking for guidance because I don't know where to start.  I've looked at:
http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html  and
http://michaeljswart.com/2008/06/splitting-and-joining-strings-in-sql-server/  and I'm confused about how to get started.  Thx.

Comment: If you want to do this in TSQL (e.g. within an Execute SQL task in your package), it's been [asked and answered](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+comma+delimited+into+rows) many times. If you want to do it in an SSIS component, then using a Script task may be easiest because you can simply use the [.NET String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method.

Comment: Sorry to bother you Pondlife.  I'll go elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make it a ragged right or fixed length destination and then have a comma as the text qualifier?